# How do I show a Dialog Box on my home screen as soon as it loads in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, dialog

I want to show a dialog box as soon as my home screen loads up with the dialog box containing 4 clickable images in a grid view. The images will be routed to individual screens. I am unaware of a way to implement this. Could use some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use stateful widget to show a dialog when screen loads so do it like this,

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          showDialog(); // your dialong goes here
    }
  }
}
```

Note when you are using `inistate` you don't have access to context so you required use a `postFrameCallBack` so that whenever context is available the function will get executed.